# The EISDIR 4068 error when trying to unzip file with Node.js zlib

Tags: node.js, zlib

When I try to unzip a zip file with my Node.js app using only built-in module zlib, I get the EISDIR 4068 error.

Here is my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require('zlib');
const path = require('path');

const zipFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'test.zip');
const unzipDirectory = path.join(__dirname, 'unzipdir');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath);
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(unzipDirectory);

readStream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(writeStream);

writeStream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('Unzip process completed.');
});

readStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error reading ZIP file:', err);
});

writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error writing unzip directory:', err);
});
```

How to resolve the problem?

Node.js v18

Comment: `fs.createWriteStream(unzipDirectory);` will create a *file*  and not a *directory*

Comment: And if that `unzipDirectory` already exists as a directory, an `EISDIR` error seems plausible, because you cannot write data on a directory

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks! How to make the code correct?

Comment: Do you have a `.zip` file or a `.gz` file? Those are two totally different formats. You cannot unzip a `.zip`  file with `zlib`. This is only for `.gz` files. And a `.gz` file cannot contain multiple compressed files, but is typically the compressed version of a single file ..

Comment: If you just want to create a new uncompressed file in an existing `unzip` directory, just use `const unzipFile = path.join(__dirname, 'unzipdir', 'filename`);` and use that filename in `const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(unzipFile);`

Comment: @derpirscher I have a zip file, but it doesn't matter for me which format to use. I just need to unpack archive with a file and I can create GZ file as well before unpacking

Comment: `Gunzip` will not read a zip file. gzip and zip are entirely different formats.